# Symfony 3 / APCu + PHP7

Tags: php, symfony, apc, php-7, apcu

I have a problem with APCu and PHP7 again.
Here is my conf.

```
framework:
    validation:
        cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apc
    serializer:
        cache: serializer.mapping.cache.apc

doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
```

Website works ok, but when I send a form, I always get this error:

> [2016-06-29 09:17:12] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException:
>   "Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace
>   "Doctrine\Common\Cache"." at
>   ROUTE_TO_PROJECT/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php
>   line 41 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException(code:
>   0): Attempted to call function \"apc_fetch\" from namespace
>   \"Doctrine\Common\Cache\". at
>   ROUTE_TO_PROJECT/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php:41)"}
>   []

here is my composer:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.5",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "gopay/payments-sdk-php": "^1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

Why is Symfony call apc_fetch instead apcu_fatch?

Answer (score 5):

In previous versions of `APCu`, the `APC` module and functions were provided as part of the library.

In the most recent (PHP 7) versions of `APCu`, backward compatible `APC` is a [separate extension](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu-bc).

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

services.yml

```
serializer.mapping.cache.apcu:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache
```

confing_prod.yml

```
serializer:
    cache: serializer.mapping.cache.apcu
```

Idk if this solution is ok, but looks like it works. So if you know better solution, I would like to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get apcu working with symfony validation using the doctrine cache wrapper

config.yml

```
validation:
    cache: validator.mapping.cache
```

services.yml

```
doctrine.apcu.cache:
      class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache

validator.mapping.cache:
      class: Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache
      arguments: ['@doctrine.apcu.cache']
```